# Error opening tftp:// (Time Out)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, networking, cisco

There i am trying to copy my running-config file from Cisco Access Point to
my Linux machine /tftpboot/ directory, but there i am getting issue like

`user@device#telnet 192.168.xxx.x`
`Trying 192.168.xxx.x...`
`Connected to 192.168.xxx.x (192.168.xxx.x).`
`Escape character is '^]'.`

`User Access Verification`

`Username: Cisco`
`Password:`
`ap>en`
`Password:`
`ap#copy running-config tftp:`
`Address or name of remote host []? 192.168.xxx.x`
`Destination filename [ap-confg]? backup_config_192_168_xxx_x`
`.....`
`%Error opening tftp://192.168.xxx.x/backup_config_192_168_xxx_x (Timed out)`

There i have set the firewall rule also on my Linux machine as given command

`(/sbin/iptables -L INPUT | /bin/grep 192.168.xxx.x | /bin/grep tftp || /sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p UDP -i eth0.100 -s 192.168.xxx.x --dport 69 -j ACCEPT) > /dev/null 2>&1`
`/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0.100 -s 192.168.xxx.x -p udp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT > /dev/null 2>&1`
`/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0.100 -s 192.168.xxx.x -p udp -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT > /dev/null 2>&1`

eth0.100 is interface for access point

Answer (score 0):

What permissions does the directory have? You can make it temporarily accessible for everyone to try. CHMOD777 /tftpboot

Comment: I have changed to full read, write and execute (777) permission to the same directory but still i am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you checked that port 69 is listening `netstat -4lupen`
and also have pinged the server from the switch.
I don't know what linux you are using, but on debian I had this issue. No idea why. I just installed another tftp server and it worked (tftpd-hpa)